# Attempted import error with Server Components in Next.js app directory

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

I have a very basic page that I use to experiment with React Server Components in an existing Next.js app:

```js
// src/app/empty/page.tsx
import { Footer } from "components/layout/footer/footer";

export default function EmptyPage() {
  console.log("EmptyPage");
  return (
    <>
      <div className="border-white-10% m-2 inline-block border p-2">
        <h1>Empty Page</h1>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

I run `next dev` and visit `http://localhost:3000/empty`. The page appears, the footer is rendered and I see the following in *server* console:

```
./src/hooks/use-client-side-value.ts
Attempted import error: 'useEffect' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'useEffect').

Import trace for requested module:
./src/hooks/use-client-side-value.ts
./src/components/layout/footer/social-buttons.tsx
./src/components/layout/footer/footer.tsx
EmptyPage
```

Each of footer.tsx, social-buttons.tsx and use-client-side-value.ts has `"use client";` at the top, so it should be safe to use useEffect there, right? What am I doing wrong?

Full code of the components:

```js
// footer.tsx
"use client";
import React from "react";
import SocialButtons from "./social-buttons";

interface FooterProps {
  hasLargePadding?: boolean;
}

export const Footer = ({ hasLargePadding = true }: FooterProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`px-3 md:px-6 ${hasLargePadding && "lg:px-18"}`}
    >
      <SocialButtons />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
// social-buttons.tsx
"use client";
import { useClientSideValue } from "hooks/use-client-side-value";
import { isAndroid, isIOS } from "react-device-detect";
import SocialButton from "./social-button";

const SocialButtons = () => {
  const facebookSchemeUri = useClientSideValue(() => {
    if (isIOS) return "fb://profile/112142838181341";
    if (isAndroid) return "fb://page/112142838181341";
    return undefined;
  });

  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <SocialButton
        href="https://facebook.com/company"
        schemeUri={facebookSchemeUri}
        icon={<img src="/assets/icons/facebook.svg" alt="Facebook" />}
      />
      <SocialButton
        href="https://instagram.com/company"
        icon={
          <img
            src="/assets/icons/instagram.svg"
            alt="Instagram"
            style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}
          />
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SocialButtons;
```

```js
// hooks/use-client-side-value.ts
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function useClientSideValue<T>(callback: () => T) {
  const [clientSideValue, setClientSideValue] = useState<undefined | T>();

  useEffect(() => {
    setClientSideValue(callback());
  }, []);

  return clientSideValue;
}
```

Comment: Please include the code from the relevant files in your problem description - `footer.tsx`, `social-button.tsx`, `use-client-side-value.ts`

Comment: @hersh Added at the bottom!

Comment: @Terry Yes! In my case, though, adding Chrome 118 to browserlist wasn't enough, I had to remove target: es5 from tsconfig.json as well. Add an answer, if you want, and I'll accept it